# Collapsing offsets of cstructs in the Racket FFI

Tags: c, struct, racket, padding, ffi

I have a large cstruct that has two fields in the middle describing a list size and a pointer to the list:

```
(define-cstruct _context
  (...
   [size _uint]
   [lst _pointer]
   ...)
```

However, to get to this list I always first need to grab the size, then convert the pointer to the list of the given size. Obviously I could make a function to do this:

```
(define (convert-to-list size clst)
  ...)
```

But I think we can do better. Namely, I would like to have the field 'feel' like it is a Racket list/vector without having to constantly pass it to `convert-to-list`. We can get most of the way there with another `define-cstruct`, say we do:

```
(define _clist
  (let ()
    (define-cstruct _clist
      ([size _uint]
       [lst _pointer])
    (make-ctype _clist #f
      (lambda (v)
        (cblock->list (ptr-ref (clist-lst v) _pointer)
                      _pointer
                      (clist-count v))))))
```

And now I can put this new struct back in the old struct:

```
(define-cstruct _context
  (...
   [lst _clist]
   ...))
```

The problem is that `_clist` is now read a a C data type, which means it tries to use standard C offsets for this new struct, rather than 'inlining' the data, so to speak.

Is there any way that I can use this pattern while getting Racket to use padding as if the new cstruct was written directly with the outer one?

(Obviously I could use Racket's metaprogramming to inline the struct, but that is using the nuclear option, which I'd like to avoid if I don't need it.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there actually is a way to get the inner cstruct (`_clist`) to pad itself as if it was defined inline, by using the `#:alignment` keyword in [`define-cstruct`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/C_Struct_Types.html?q=define-cstruct#%28form._%28%28lib._ffi%2Funsafe..rkt%29._define-cstruct%29%29).

Simply give the inner struct `#:alignment 1`, and it will align itself with no extra padding.

Your resulting code should look like:

```
(define _clist
  (let ()
    (define-cstruct _clist
      ([size _uint]
       [lst _pointer]
      #:alignment 1)
    (make-ctype _clist #f
      (lambda (v)
        (cblock->list (ptr-ref (clist-lst v) _pointer)
                      _pointer
                      (clist-count v))))))
```

And now you can use your new in the outer struct as if a list with a length was provided directly:

```
(define-cstruct _context
  (...
   [lst _clist]
   ...))
```

Thank you to Matthew Flatt for helping me come to this answer.